# PYTHON(2.7): List comprehension - Adding(sum) numbers in a .txt file with additional text

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make this code run a certain way. I'm trying to make it so there is a text file I have with both words and numbers in. The code needs to extract either positive or negative numbers and then add them together. Below, I have an example of what it looks like in the text file minus the bullet points. I'm trying to make it the shortest amount of code(as any code should be written) using list comprehension. I'm still a novice coder, so any help is appreciated.

---

```
example of text and numbers in file

 - Positive 36
 - Negative: -12
 - Negative: -11
 - Positive: 42
 - Positive: 95
 - Negative: -4
```

---

Here is a rough attempt of code. I'm having most trouble (in theory) trying to implement whether I want to grab positive or negative numbers:

```
    sum([int(line.strip()) for line in open("text.txt").readlines()])
```

Answer (score 1):

split on whitespace and get the second element which is the integer:

```
with open("text.txt") as f: # using with closes your files automaticlly
    print sum([int(line.split()[1]) for line in f.readlines()])
146
```

You can also just iterate over the file object without using readlines:

```
with open("out.txt") as f:
   print sum([int(line.split()[1]) for line in f])
```

If you used  `print ([line.split() for line in f])` the output would look like:

```
 [['Positive', '36'], ['Negative:', '-12'], ['Negative:', '-11'], ['Positive:', '42'], ['Positive:', '95'], ['Negative:', '-4']]
```

so you can see how `line.split()[1]` gets the integer.

Comment: And this is exactly why I love Python so much :)

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke, I agree, a little does a lot :)

Comment: @user3795450, only you can decide if you want negative or positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the sign of the number from just the number, so split each line and grab the last part:

```
with open('text.txt') as handle:
    numbers = (int(line.split()[1]) for line in handle)

total = sum(n for n in numbers if n > 0)
```

There's no need to call `readlines` on the file object, as iterating over the file object itself gives you all of the lines one at a time. Also, using a generator expression uses two less characters and will work faster for larger text files, as there's no intermediate list.

Comment: why have you used `total = sum(n for n in numbers if n > 0)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Because OP wants to sum only the positive (or negative) numbers.

Comment: I don't think they do,"The code needs to extract either positive or negative numbers and then add them together"

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: It says either, not both. This seems more like a question the OP is better suited to answer.

Comment: I only asked as I thought there was maybe something not very obvious I might be missing in your code but the fact the OP's code is in a single list comp makes seems pretty clear that all positive and negative numbers are added together.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry I haven't been able to answer as quickly. I took a break because it was giving me a headache. My goal is to, for instant select somewhere in the code that I want the positive numbers. And then add the positive numbers together. I just want the sum returned. The reason I put either is because I was thinking somewhere in the code I could change "Positive" to "Negative, which would then return the sum of the negative numbers. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Blender look above! thanks for the help so far guys. I haven't solved it, but it's leading me to a better solution